# No Dependencies are automatically installed when adding nuget package

Tags: tfs, package, nuget, .net-standard, build-definition

I'm creating a small nuget package for internal using (I created .NET standard project to use both .NET Framework or .NET Core). I created a Build Definition to build the library then push it to the Nuget Feeds of my company.

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I set it automatically increase the version of the my nuget package when Queue the build in tfs 2017 & Can I set some information like Author, Company...for my package?
2. After having the Package in the TFS Packages. I tried to add my nuget package to my project. The nuget referenced package were not automatically added to the project. I can see, it displayed "No dependencies" but in fact, I used 2 packages in my library are Newtonsoft & StackExchange.Redis. So when I run the debug, error shown "Could not find the StackExchange.Redis..."

That's strange

[image: No dependencies displayed]

In my Libary project setting, I can see

[image: Library configuration]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to package nuget packages.  You can use "nuget pack" or "dotnet pack" (if you have some dotnet core in your solution).  The difference is that dotnet pack will create a dependency section in your nuspec and you would see dependency upon installing where nuget pack will not by default unless you use an actual nuspec file.  If you do create a nuspec file, you'll need to add the dependency section to you file in order to have them pop up at installation.  Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) for info on the nuspec file.

For you version number it's also actually in the nuspec file in the metadata section there is a  tag with the version you want.  The TFS nuget pack task as a drop down you can use to send in a version number. For this task you can either use a nuspec file or the csproj directly.

[image]

You have the same options for dotnet pack using the dotnet core task
[image]

**Update:**

If you change your build number version pattern in the options tab for a 4 (or 3) digit pattern like $(Date:yyyy.MM.dd).$(Rev:r) e.g. 2020.03.05.xx (where xx will increment for each build in the same day and go down to 1 the next day) or 1.0.$(Rev:r) which will be 1.0.xx that will increment forever until you change the 1.0 value and then use the "Use Build Number" it will do it for you.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Etienne, I'm now able to have dependencies while using dotnet pack command. About the version increment, I think I have to write some powershell script to update the Variable values: Majo.Minor.Sub.Build. Do you know how to have that kind of powershell script?